# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:

Tags: c#, wpf, nlog

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''The invocation of the constructor on type 'VIGIL_NLogViewer.NLogViewer' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '286' and line position '18'.'

I am getting this error whenever i am adding another project which is i have copied from YouTube it works fine , butt when i want to use this project in another it show this error  [image][image]`

```
<Window x:Class="VIGIL_2._0.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:nlog ="clr-namespace:NlogViewer;assembly=NlogViewer"
        xmlns:fa="clr-namespace:FontAwesome.WPF;assembly=FontAwesome.WPF"
        xmlns:Logger="clr-namespace:VIGIL_NLogViewer;assembly=VIGIL_NLogViewer"
        xmlns:WindowsPresentation="clr-namespace:GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation;assembly=GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Title="{Binding MainWindowTitle}" MinWidth="900" MinHeight="700" Width="808.5" Height="700" 
        ResizeMode="CanResize" Closing="Window_Closing"
```

`

```
 <TabItem Header="Log" Style="{StaticResource TextFormat}">
                <Logger:NLogViewer x:Name="NLogViewer1" LogTargetName="target1" />
            </TabItem>
```

`
// NLog Config file

```
 <targets>
    <target xsi:type="CacheTarget" name="target1"/>
    <target xsi:type="CacheTarget" name="target2"/>
    <!--
    add your targets here
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Targets for possible targets.
    See https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers for the possible layout renderers.
    -->
    <target xsi:type="File"
           name="default"
           layout="${longdate} - ${level:uppercase=true}: ${message}${onexception:${newline}EXCEPTION\: ${exception:format=ToString}}"
           fileName="${specialfolder:ApplicationData}\A1Fence2.0.0\VIGIL\VIGIL.log"
           keepFileOpen="false"
           archiveFileName="${specialfolder:ApplicationData}\A1Fence2.0.0\VIGIL\VIGIL_${shortdate}.{##}.log"
           archiveNumbering="Sequence"
           archiveEvery="Month"
           maxArchiveFiles="12"
            />

    <target xsi:type="Database"
            name="database"
            keepConnection="false"
            useTransactions="true"
            dbProvider="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data"
            connectionString=" server=192.168.5.205; Database=liminal_k; user id=master1; password=master1@1Fence"
            commandText="insert into vigil_logs (UserName, Application, Logged, Level, Message,UserIP,SystemMAC) values (@argument, @Application, @Logged, @Level, @Message, @argument1, @argument2);">

      <parameter name="@application" layout="VIGIL" />
      <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@argument" layout="${event-properties:item=UserName}"/>
      <parameter name="@argument1" layout="${event-properties:item=UserIP}" />
      <parameter name="@argument2" layout="${event-properties:item=SystemMAC}" />
      <!--<parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite:filename=true}" />-->
      <!--<parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />-->
    </target>
    <!--
    Write events to a file with the date in the filename.
   
    -->
    
    
    <target xsi:type="NLogViewer" name="ctrl" />
     
    <!--</target>-->
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="default" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ctrl" />
    <!--<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="Database" />-->
    <logger name="*" writeTo="target1" maxlevel="Info"/>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="target2" minlevel="Warn"/>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="default" />

      <!--
    Write all events with minimal level of Debug (So Debug, Info, Warn, Error and Fatal, but not Trace)  to "f"
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="f" />
-->
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

`

How can i solve this issue it is argent i don't have much knowledge about this

Comment: The exception is generated by your code: try to check the indicated line for class VGIL_NLogViewer which should be the default constructor

Comment: You're expecting nlog to be able to write to a wpf window?

Comment: Your X:Class namespace seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Andy I don't understand what you mean I thing I have found the issue but how to resolve i dont know  I have code like this on Nlog window after commit this works but the log will not show on the window                                                           //private ObservableCollection<LogEventInfo> _LogEventInfos { get; } = new ObservableCollection<LogEventInfo>();
       // private IDisposable _Subscription;
        //private Window _ParentWindow;

Comment: Your namespace as in VIGIL_2._0.MainWindow . The project that is in is not called VIGIL_2._0